# Not logging GET requests on Apache based on a query string parameter presense

Tags: regex, apache

I am working on a `PCI` project and I have been asked to not log any GET request on an Apache 2 server as long as there is a query string parameter present on the URL.

I have been trying to use `SetEnvIf` and `SetEnvIfNoCase` as noted below with no success at all, the requests keep getting logged on the `access.log` for apache.

I am at a lost here, so any help would be appreciated. by the way, I am not versed on Apache by any means.

```
SetEnvIfNocase Referer "^(SECRET=)$" dontlog

CustomLog /path/to/logs combined env=!dontlog
```

Answer (score 0):

The anchors `^` and `$` prevent the referrer from matching.  Right now, you only match referrers that are exactly "SECRET=", and I doubt that's the idea.  Remove the anchors and it should work.